# How to identify which process the received TCP traffic belongs to with DTrace on macOS

Tags: mac-osx, dtrace

As can be seen here we have PID available on send but not receive. How to limit the probes to connections owned/initiated by a particular process?

```
sudo dtrace -n 'tcp:::receive, tcp:::send { printf("PID = %d, arg1 == %x", pid, arg1); }'
dtrace: description 'tcp:::receive, tcp:::send ' matched 2 probes
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 13507, arg1 == ffffff80664413c0
  0   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  0   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 13507, arg1 == ffffff80664f6fd8
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  2   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 0, arg1 == ffffff80664f9678
  4   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 13511, arg1 == ffffff80664413c0
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 13511, arg1 == ffffff8057ee7678
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  6   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  4   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  4   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 0, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  4   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  4   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 0, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  4   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  4   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 0, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 851, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 851, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  6   1571                  tcp_output:send PID = 851, arg1 == ffffff806c2b9d18
  0   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
  0   1574                tcp_input:receive PID = 0, arg1 == 0
```

On solaris the second argument `args[1]` would be a pointer to a `csinfo_t` containing all the information I need but on Mac OS it's always null. Solaris arguments are described on the following link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36846/glhmv.html

I'm using macOS 10.13.6

Comment: This looks like the TCP receive dTrace probe:  https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/netinet/tcp_input.c#L1976  It looks like `arg2` might be what you're looking for, as this code appears to translate the `inpcb` structure to a `csinfo_t`: https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/5394bb038891708cd4ba748da79b90a33b19f82e/bsd/dev/dtrace/scripts/ip.d#L50